# Set a default value for user_url in the WordPress admin area

Tags: wordpress, admin, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to set the default value for all users who do not have user_url field populated. I am also going to try and do this on user registration but can't seem to get it going. I have stripped the code back to remove the conditionals if they have a populated field for now as am just trying to get it to update the user url!

Any help appreciated.

```
function add_info_to_post() { 

   update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_url', 'http://#' );


}

add_action( 'profile_update', 'add_info_to_post' );

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'add_info_to_post' );

add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'add_info_to_post' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_pre_insert_user_data` filter in `functions.php`.

```
$data = array('user_url' => 'http://example.com');
apply_filters( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', $data );
```

Documentation is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_pre_insert_user_data/).

Comment: This was useful and sent me on the right path thanks! the following code worked in the end!

 add_filter( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', function ($data, $update) {
  if ($update) return $data;
  $data['user_url'] = 'http://#';
  return $data;
}, 99, 2);